# How to insert table header before first match in XSL-FO?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

Howdy.

I have an unusual situation where a table of products is built based on a series of conditionals. However, because of limitations of the tool processing the XSL, I need to to insert a header before the first result of the choose/when statement.

I've tried this to no avail:

````
                     <xsl:when test="number(translate($_dsSub1/lotCharges_l, ',', '.'))&#62;&#39;0&#39; or number(translate($_dsSub1/price/_price_item_price_each, ',', '.'))&#62;&#39;0&#39; or $_dsSub1/leadTimeMax_l&#62;&#39;0&#39; and $_dsSub1/item_l/_part_custom_field8 = &#39;Services&#39;">
                        <xsl:choose>                      
                          <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                            <h1>Table Header goes here</h1>
                          </xsl:when>
                          <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                        <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="1" padding="5px" margin="0px" border-collapse="collapse" top="0px" bottom="0px" height="5px">
...```
````

Comment: Can you include a sample of the XML? It's hard to understand the context without it. What XSLT version are you using? 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0?

Comment: I can't actually see the XML -- which is bonkers -- but the system uses XSLT 1.0

Comment: Essentially, what happens is the the first When test matches products of the specified types whose prices aren't zero. I'm looking to add a table header before the first one that meets that match. Otherwise, because this snippet is within a For-each loop, the header gets applied to every single price that matches.

Comment: H1 is not xsl fo

Answer (score 0):

The non-header `fo:table-row` must be in an `fo:table-body`.  The table header needs to be in an `fo:table-header` that precedes the `fo:table-body`. See this graphic at https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#d0e11407

[image: A tree representation of table Formatting Objects showing how they fit within one another.]

So before the `<fo:table-body>`, you want something like:

```
<xsl:if test="position() = 1">
  <fo:table-header>
    <fo:table-row>
      ...
    </fo:table-row>
  </fo:table-header>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: The conditional to trigger the display happens further downstream in the XML & XSL. How might I trigger header if we do not know yet if it is needed?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up moving the conditional logic from the individual table rows and put the where clause before the table is being built.